# Decrease cyclomatic complexity of settings verification

Tags: c#

I have a brownfield application which has a complex method.  The CC is 14.  The if statements verify application settings and generate the appropriate inline SQL.

E.G. This if statement checks the settings.  settings is custom code, a DTO with several `bool` (**not** `bool?`) properties.

```
        string conditions = " AND (";

        List<string> conditionStrings = new List<string>();

        if (settings.AlwaysIncludeCommonResults && settings.SelectedCommonLabs.Count > 0)
        {
            string common = " (Table.Name in (";
            for (int i = 0; i < settings.SelectedCommonLabs.Count; i++)
            {
                common += string.Format("'{0}'", settings.SelectedCommonLabs[i]);
                if (i < settings.SelectedCommonLabs.Count - 1)
                    common += ", ";
            }
            common += ")) ";
            conditionStrings.Add(common);
        }

        if (settings.AlwaysSelectLast24HoursResults)
        {
            string last24 = " (DateDiff(hh, Table.PerformedDtm, GetDate()) < 24) ";
            conditionStrings.Add(last24);
        }
```

I don't know what to do to simplify this bool logic.  Null coalesce?...I don't know that it will make this any better.  This pattern appears several more times in the same method.  So I hope to reuse the answer several times to decrease overall CC and increase readability.  What do you suggest?

**UPDATED**
After deciding to rip out the first verification, added further method logic.

Comment: This looks and feels wrong... Why should the code waste time building a complex SQL statement if no results will be returned ?

Comment: @alex - Agreed.  I should rip this up at a higher level.  The method does still need to exist (remember there are more if statements like this) for when the query has real conditions.  So any suggestions to improve this type of logic are still helpful.

Comment: I'd be curious to see other pieces of that method .. maybe there are other place where you can just *not* perform checks instead of trying to fix them. It's not easy to fix a complex sequence without seeing it altogether.

Comment: @Alex - updated.  IMO, the code is pretty horrendous.  Hopefully there will be something to salvage here...

Comment: I'd suggest *at least* moving the code in a bunch of stored procedures you can drive with simple parameters, or (way better) parameterized `SqlCommand`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by shrinking code a bit:

```
   string common = " (Table.Name in (";
            for (int i = 0; i < settings.SelectedCommonLabs.Count; i++)
            {
                common += string.Format("'{0}'", settings.SelectedCommonLabs[i]);
                if (i < settings.SelectedCommonLabs.Count - 1)
                    common += ", ";
            }
            common += ")) ";
            conditionStrings.Add(common);
```

can be shrunk:

```
string common = " (Table.Name in (";
//if SelectedCommonLabs is a collection of strings, LINQ your way through it
common += string.Join(", ", settings.SelectedCommonLabs.ToList().Select(lab => string.Format("'{0}'",lab)));
common += ")) ";
conditionStrings.Add(common);
```

But I agree this is not very nice code to begin with.

Comment: This is why I say inline SQL is evil.  Not because the technology itself is unreadable, because the things developers tend to do with the technology is evil.

Comment: Agreed 101% also injection issues might arise

Comment: The original was just a long winded Join. Good job converting that method! – P.Brian.Mackey 17 mins ago